# Optimizing Excel formulas - SUMPRODUCT vs SUMIFS/COUNTIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

According to a couple of web sites, SUMIFS and COUNTIFS are faster than SUMPRODUCT (for example: http://exceluser.com/blog/483/excels-sumifs-or-sumproduct-which-is-faster.html). I have a worksheet with an unknown number of rows (around 200 000) and I'm calculating performance reports with the numbers. I have over 6000 times almost identical SUMPRODUCT formulas with a couple of difference each times (only the conditions change).

Here is an example of what I got:

```
=IF(AFO4>0,
(SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$N:$N=$A4)
*(LEFT(Sheet1!$H:$H,2)="1A")
*(Sheet1!$M:$M<>"service catalog")
*(Sheet1!$J:$J="incident")
*(Sheet1!$I:$I<>"self-serve")
*(Sheet1!$AK:$AK=AFM$1)
*(Sheet1!$E:$E>=$E$1)
*(Sheet1!$E:$E<$E$2))
+SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$AJ:$AJ=$C4)
*(LEFT(Sheet1!$H:$H,2)="1A")
*(Sheet1!$M:$M<>"service catalog")
*(Sheet1!$J:$J="incident")
*(Sheet1!$I:$I="self-serve")
*(Sheet1!$AK:$AK=AFM$1)
*(Sheet1!$E:$E>=$E$1)
*(Sheet1!$E:$E<$E$2)))/AFO4,0)
```

Calculating that thing takes a little bit more than 1 second. Since I have more than 6000 of those formulas, it takes a little bit over an hour to calculate everything.

So, I'm now looking at how I could optimize that formula. Could I convert it to SUMIFS? Would it be faster? All I'm adding up here is 0s and 1s, I'm just counting the number of rows in my data source (`Sheet1`) where the set of conditions is met. Maybe COUNTIFS would work better?

I would appreciate any help to gain some execution time since we need to execute the formulas every month.

I can use VBA if that helps, but I always heard that Excel formulas were usually faster.

Comment: Typically COUNTIFS will be approx 3 times quicker - you can use a wildcard in place of the LEFT criterion

Comment: @pnuts I have some more restrictions that would prevent me from using filters efficiently. These 6000 formulas are the worst part of a 200k formulas worksheet. The `SUMPRODUCTS` above take more than 90% of the execution time to calculate the whole worksheet.

Comment: @barryhoudini Could you post an example as an answer on how you would convert my `SUMPRODUCT` to a `COUNTIFS` with only my first `SUMPRODUCT` above and the first 2 criterias? I'm just unsure about what you mean by using a wildcard.

Comment: a wild card in `COUNTIFS` is `*` so `(LEFT(Sheet1!$H:$H,2)="1A")` could be put into `COUNTIFS` as `COUNTIF(Sheet1!$H:$H,"1A*")` which anything then that starts with `1A` would be counted

Comment: That's right, so 1st SUMPRODUCT could become `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$N:$N,$A4,Sheet1!$H:$H,"1A*",Sheet1!$M:$M,"<>service catalog",Sheet1!$J:$J,"incident",Sheet1!$I:$I,"<>self-serve",Sheet1!$AK:$AK,AFM$1,Sheet1!$E:$E,">="&$E$1,Sheet1!$E:$E,"<"&$E$2)`

Comment: Excellent, I will give this a try this afternoon, thank you.

Comment: COUNTIFS and SUMIFS short-circuit each condition (if the condition fails they do not go on to evaluate the next condition), so you should put the most restrictive condition first, the next most restrictive second etc.

Comment: FWIW, while  a pair of `COUNTIFS` would be a more efficient formula and can use full columns range references without detriment, your original sumproduct would have benefited from columns ranges like `Sheet1!$N2:$N200000` instead of full columns references.

Comment: COUNTIFS works and is way more than 3x faster. I will give the exact number a little bit later but it looks like at least 10x faster right now.

Comment: I'm feeling bad about how big the difference is. What took almost 72 minutes before to calculate is now taking 47 seconds for the exact same results. It is ~92x faster.

Comment: COUNTIFS is around 3* faster (using FastExcel from Charles) for the standard amount of conditions (2-3)  - your formula is much more complicated.

Comment: That's probably why. Before: 4319 seconds. After: 47 seconds. Speaking of improvement would be an understatement. @barryhoudini You can post your comment as a complete answer if you wish to.

Comment: I didn't think it would be that much quicker! I posted as an answer as you suggest

Comment: @ Charles Williams - I didn't know the order of the conditions made a difference, excellent advice! Presumably that would apply to `AVERAGEIFS` too?

Comment: If it does, that would be great information to add to your answer. I would like to see some benchmarks on that however. But from a pure theorical standpoint, I always put the most restrictive condition first anyway, just for the sake of clarity.

Comment: But that makes sense, Excel has no reason to check the second criteria if the first isn't met, thus less conditions are checked overall if the first condition is more restrictive, especially on such a big range as 6k formulas.

Comment: @Barry, yes it applies to all the  COUNTIFS, AVERAGEIFS etc functions (and my FILTER.IFS function): but not to SUMPRODUCT. And as Jeeped points out the COUNTIFS family of functions handle full column references efficiently (assuming sensible used range) but SUMPRODUCT does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st `SUMPRODUCT` could become

`=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$N:$N,$A4,Sheet1!$H:$H,"1A*",Sheet1!$M:$M,"<>service catalog",Sheet1!$J:$J,"incident",Sheet1!$I:$I,"<>self-serve",Sheet1!$AK:$AK,AFM$‌​1,Sheet1!$E:$E,">="&$E$1,Sheet1!$E:$E,"<"&$E$2)`

The `LEFT` part can be handled by a wildcard, as shown

change the second part along the same lines

Answer (score 7):

Instead of formulas, Why not use a PivotTable to crunch the numbers? You potentially face a longer one-time hit to load the data into the PivotCache, but after that, you should find a PivotTable recalculates much faster in response to filter changes than these computationally expensive formulas. Is there any reason you're not using one?

Here's some content from a book I'm writing, where I compare SUMPRODUCT, SUMIFS, DSUM, PivotTables, the Advanced Filter, and something called Range Slicing (which uses clever combinations of INDEX/MATCH on sorted data) to  conditionally sum the records in a table that contains over 1 million sales records, based on choices you make from 10 different dropdowns:

Those dropdowns allow you to filter the database by a combination of the Store, Segment, Species, Gender, Payment, Cust. History, Order Status, Delivery Instructions, Membership Type, and Order Channel columns. So there’s some pretty mammoth filtering and aggregation going on in order to reduce those 1 million records down to just one sum. The file outlines six different ways to achieve this outcome, the first three of which are shown in the screenshot below:
[image: First Three Options]

As you’d expect, when all those dropdowns are set to the same settings, you get exactly the same answer out of all six approaches. But what you won’t expect is just how slow SUMPRODUCT is to calculate a new answer if you change one of those dropdowns, compared to the other approaches.
In fact, it turns out that the SUMIFS approach is 15 times faster than the SUMPRODUCT one at coming up with the answer on this mammoth dataset. But that’s nothing: The range slicing approach is 56 times faster!

The Range Slicing approach works by sorting your source data, and then using a series of clever formulas in helper columns to cleverly identifying exactly where any records of interest sit within that sorted data. This means that you can then directly sum just the few records that match rather than having to do a complex criteria match against hundreds of thousands of rows (or against a million rows, as in the example here).

Here’s how that looks in terms of my sample file. The number in the Rows helper column on the right-hand side shows that through some clever elimination, the SUM function at the bottom has to process only 18 rows of data (rows 292996 through 293014) rather than all 1 million rows. In other words, this is mighty efficient.

[image]

And here’s the second group of alternatives:

[image: Next three options]

Yup, you can quite easily use a PivotTable here. And the PivotTable approach seems to be around 6 times faster than SUMPRODUCT—although you get a small amount of extra delay when calling up the filters, and the first time you perform a filter operation it takes quite a bit longer again, as Excel must load the PivotCache into memory. But let’s face it: Setting up the PivotTable in the first place is the easiest of any of these approaches, so it has my vote.

The DSUM approach is 12 times faster than SUMPRODUCT. That’s not as good as SUMIFS, but it’s still a significant improvement. The Advanced Filter approach is only 4 times faster than SUMPRODUCT—which isn’t really surprising because what it does is grab an extract of all records from the source data that match the criteria in that list, dump it into the spreadsheet, and then sum the result.

Comment: Well, this is really interesting. I'm not sure if it's applicable though. I have over 2000 columns of data, but it's split into different parts: information on the employees are in the first columns, then the data from their timesheet, then a couple of hundreds of columns of data on their phone calls (call center stats), then on some other activities (we get inquiries from a web form too) and so much more (all split for each months). Also, in my experience, pivot tables tend to have a problem when used for a 200x2000 table (we are now over 400k cells/formulas).

Comment: Also, I mostly need to really have that spreadsheet with all the information (>400k cells) available at the same time to do my charts. Anyway, it did improve a lot with SUMIFS. Calculating the 400k cells takes around 1 hour instead of ~30 hours. The longest part is actually the manual validation of the data sources (i.e. employees not entering their timesheet properly) rather than the 1h CPU time needed (which can be done during launch, which wasn't the case when this was 30+ hours).

Comment: Where does the data come from? This sounds unsustainable to me...especially if the data is going to grow over time. I think the best approach will be to connect Excel to the database or databases concerned, and just suck through the data already aggregated to how you need it.

Comment: I don't have access directly to the database due to security reasons, which indeed sucks. The data stops to grow when the year ends because we start with a new workbook every year and the data from the previous years get read-only (in short the formulas are converted into values for the previous year). I get the data from 4 different databases, usually through Excel exportations. Making a new database with Access would have been more efficient, but they specifically wanted it to be designed with Excel.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have? I take it those SUMIFS are pretty much doing the same thing as SQL joins would? Can you use MS Query (which is part of Excel)  or one of the PowerBI tools like PowerQuery or PowerPivot (if you have the right version of Excel) to create these reports from the various tables with no formulas whatsoever?

Comment: We've got Excel 2010. I could use MS Query, but at this point I don't think it would be worth starting everything over.