# UDF with Intersect runs slow

Tags: vba, performance, excel

So I am creating a function to replace some manual index/match formulas. Note that this function works, but my problem is with speed. So I have a PivotTable with 6 columns and approx. 200.000 rows. I want this to find the value (and I don't use the pivotfunctions, meaning that this is just a table in pivot format) I found that this runs faster than having it in a regular data table. Both would be imported from a SQL table.

A single piece of this formula runs instantly, but the performance slows down when I have a few hundreds in the same sheet.

So any ideas on how to speed this up?

```
Function getnum2(ByVal Comp As String, Period As String, Measure As String, Optional BU As String, _
    Optional Country As String, Optional Table As String, Optional TableSheet As String) As Double

Dim pTable As PivotTable, wTableSheet As Worksheet

If BU = "" Then
    BU = "Group"
End If
If Country = "" Then
    Country = "Total"
End If
If TableSheet = "" Then
    Set wTableSheet = Worksheets("Data")
Else
    Set wTableSheet = Worksheets(TableSheet)
End If
If Table = "" Then
    Set pTable = wTableSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Else
    Set pTable = wTableSheet.PivotTables(Table)
End If

'Find match
If Intersect(pTable.PivotFields("Bank").PivotItems(Comp).DataRange.EntireRow, _
    pTable.PivotFields("Date").PivotItems(Period).DataRange.EntireRow, _
    pTable.PivotFields("Business Unit").PivotItems(BU).DataRange.EntireRow, _
    pTable.PivotFields("Country").PivotItems(Country).DataRange.EntireRow, _
    pTable.PivotFields("Name").PivotItems(Measure).DataRange) Is Nothing Then
        getnum2 = "No match"
ElseIf Intersect(pTable.PivotFields("Bank").PivotItems(Comp).DataRange.EntireRow, _
    pTable.PivotFields("Date").PivotItems(Period).DataRange.EntireRow, _
    pTable.PivotFields("Business Unit").PivotItems(BU).DataRange.EntireRow, _
    pTable.PivotFields("Country").PivotItems(Country).DataRange.EntireRow, _
    pTable.PivotFields("Name").PivotItems(Measure).DataRange).Count > 1 Then
        getnum2 = "More than 1 match"
Else
    getnum2 = Intersect(pTable.PivotFields("Bank").PivotItems(Comp).DataRange.EntireRow, _
    pTable.PivotFields("Date").PivotItems(Period).DataRange.EntireRow, _
    pTable.PivotFields("Business Unit").PivotItems(BU).DataRange.EntireRow, _
    pTable.PivotFields("Country").PivotItems(Country).DataRange.EntireRow, _
    pTable.PivotFields("Name").PivotItems(Measure).DataRange)
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Any reason you don't simply use GETPIVOTDATA to reference the coordinates in the PivotTable you want? It's a bit hard to offer suggestions without knowing more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: What I am trying to do is just to find a way to reference specific numbers from an SQL table. The way I found to be the best so far is to import data into a pivottable from an external connection and do it as above. The problem with GETPIVOTDATA is that it requires me to have the "Value" in the "Value" field where I then have to chose sum, count or whatever. The way above allows me to put all variables in rows and in that way just show a simple table.

I also tried with a regular table, but that runs even slower.

Comment: Okay. So I take it you need to do lots of lookups from a table to find matches with 5 variables, and it's taking a long time. Is that correct? If so, how many actual lookups are you doing? If I understand more what it is you are actually trying to achieve with this code, I can probably give you an approach that is lightning fast.

Comment: Some kind of image would help, showing the kind of data you have, and the kind of result you want.

Comment: Okay, so I have these 5 variables as you mention, and I do 1500 lookups or so.

How do I upload an image?

Comment: Cool. So for benchmarking purposes, how long is it currently taking to perform all of these?

Comment: To upload an image, click the Edit option at the end of your original question, which will let you add an image to it. But we might not need taht now that I understand what you are doing.

Comment: Okay, let's try without then. Before the suggestion by Rory a single lookup took 0.0273 seconds. After the change it took 0.0117 seconds.

Comment: To do all 1500? Also, what version and SKU of Excel do you have? PowerPivot may be a great way to solve this (although I can think of others)

Comment: Also, is the field you want to return a numeric one, or a string?

Comment: Numeric. I set it to double.

Comment: Okay. Late here so I can't write up an answer just now, but you can use several approaches that will probably be much faster than your UDF. One is to use a PivotTable and GETPIVOTDATA, with the numeric answer field added to the values area twice: once as a count (to check if there's more than one answer) and the other as a sum (because if there is only one 'answer' then the SUM will equal the value). Another is to use something called RangeSlicing which I discuss at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745964/optimizing-excel-formulas-sumproduct-vs-sumifs-countifs/32488911#32488911

Comment: Another would be to use PowerPivot and the Data Model, but you haven't yet set out what version/SKU of Excel you are using.

Comment: It looks like your RangeSlicing also requires PowerPivot. I will look into a version with GETPIVOTDATA and see how that performs, and report back here.

Comment: RangeSlicing does not require PowerPivot, and does not use GETPIVOTDATA. Evey version of Excel has GETPIVOTDATA.

Comment: It seems that GETPIVOTDATA runs slower than intersect. (Intersect at 0.0078 seconds and GETPIVOTDATA at 0.0117)

Comment: Good to know. I'm not surprised that it's slower, given that there are two formula calls involved. It's only saving grace is that it is simpler than a UDF.

Comment: You still haven't advised what version and SKU of Excel you have.

Comment: MS Excel 2013 professional. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calling the function three times, you could use a variable:

```
Function getnum2(ByVal Comp As String, Period As String, Measure As String, Optional BU As String, _
    Optional Country As String, Optional Table As String, Optional TableSheet As String) As Double

Dim pTable As PivotTable, wTableSheet As Worksheet
Dim rgResult as Range

If BU = "" Then
    BU = "Group"
End If
If Country = "" Then
    Country = "Total"
End If
If TableSheet = "" Then
    Set wTableSheet = Worksheets("Data")
Else
    Set wTableSheet = Worksheets(TableSheet)
End If
If Table = "" Then
    Set pTable = wTableSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Else
    Set pTable = wTableSheet.PivotTables(Table)
End If

'Find match
Set rgResult = Intersect(pTable.PivotFields("Bank").PivotItems(Comp).DataRange.EntireRow, _
    pTable.PivotFields("Date").PivotItems(Period).DataRange.EntireRow, _
    pTable.PivotFields("Business Unit").PivotItems(BU).DataRange.EntireRow, _
    pTable.PivotFields("Country").PivotItems(Country).DataRange.EntireRow, _
    pTable.PivotFields("Name").PivotItems(Measure).DataRange)
if rgResult Is Nothing Then
        getnum2 = "No match"
ElseIf rgResult.Count > 1 Then
        getnum2 = "More than 1 match"
Else
    getnum2 = rgResult.Value
End If

End Function
```

Comment: That did indeed cut runtime from 0.0273 to 0.0117 and was a very simple fix. Thank you for that. I will leave it open for another 24 hours or so if someone else comes up with more efficiency gains, but if not I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One very simple way to achieve this is by using two PivotTables.

- In PivotTable 1, put all fields but the numeric one you want to
  return in the ROWS area, and put the field that you want to return in
  the VALUES area with aggregation set to COUNT.
- In PivotTable 2, put all fields but the numeric one you want to
  return in the ROWS area, and put the field that you want to return in
  the VALUES area with aggregation set to SUM or MIN or MAX (It doesn't
  matter which).

Then you can use a paramatized GETPIVOTDATA function to check PivotTable 1 to see if the thing you're looking up is unique (i.e. COUNT = 1) and if so, then look up the SUM/MIN/MAX of that item in PivotTable2. Given the item is unique, then the SUM/MIN/MAX is only operating on one number, and so does nothing to it.

Here's how that looks, using simplified data:

[image]

I've added conditional formatting to the two Pivots to highlight multiple occurances where we want to return the text 'Multiple Items', and as you can see, the formula that is populating column 6 of the Lookup table is only returning unique items as per your requirements.

Here's the formula, using Table notation as my Lookup range has been turned into an Excel Table:

`=IF(GETPIVOTDATA("6",$A$3,"1",[@1],"2",[@2],"3",[@3],"4",[@4],"5",[@5])=1,GETPIVOTDATA("6",$H$3,"1",[@1],"2",[@2],"3",[@3],"4",[@4],"5",[@5]),"Multiple Items")`

If I randomise the input cells in the Lookup table, you can see what happens when some items aren't in the PivotTable:

[image]

This approach works because the field you want to return is a numeric one, meaning you can add it to the VALUES pane of the Pivot. But you could still use this to return strings, by adding a unique ID to the source data, such as the row number, and putting that in the VALUES field, then retrieving it with the double GETPIVOTDATA lookup and using it to retrieve the associated string in the source data.

Another approach is to simply concatenate your columns into a primary key using a suitable delimiter such as the pipe character | and then use that as your lookup key. If you did a binary search on sorted data, this would be lightning fast. (I discuss this at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2015/04/23/how-much-faster-is-the-double-vlookup-trick/ ). The down side is that you wouldn't be warned in the event that there were multiple items. But it would be possible to do a second lookup using the match position returned by the first, to see if you get another result, and if so then return "Multiple Items". This would be super-fast.

Comment: As you also mention there is a posibility of using GETPIVOTDATA, but that doesn't speed up things. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do your second suggestion. (the binary search part). Could you give any hint on that?

Comment: Sorry...forgot to respond. You still interested in the Binary Search implementation?

Comment: I will be if it's possible for me to implement without 100+ hours of work. If it is too complex I will probably close this topic and be happy with the efficiency improvement already achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fastest way to do this: using Binary Match on a sorted lookup table.
On the left I have 5 columns x 1048575 rows of random numbers between 1 and 10. These have been concatenated in column G to make a non-unique key, and then sorted ascending on that key.

[image]

(Because the concatenated key is text, it gets sorted alphabetical from left to right, which is why 1|1|1|1|10 appears between 1|1|1|1|1 and 1|1|1|1|2)

I gave the data in Column G the named range of Concat to simplify the formula. My lookup formula in J2 returns the row number of the lookup item if and only if that item is unique to the dataset. The formula is:

```
=IF(OR( AND(INDEX(Concat,MATCH(I2,Concat,1))=I2, MATCH(I2,Concat,1)=1),  AND(INDEX(Concat,MATCH(I2,Concat,1))=I2,INDEX(Concat,MATCH(I2,Concat,1)-1)<>I2)),MATCH(I2,Concat,1),NA())
```

This executes in 0.01 milliseconds for one instance, for a lookup table of 1048576 rows. My double GETPIVOTDATA approach above took 6 milliseconds. So there you have it: a complex formula that gives a 600 times efficiency boost.

I can explain the formula later in need, but note that some of the complexity is due to the edge case where you may have a unique item appearing in row 1. If I leave out that edge case, then the formula is as follows:

```
=IF( AND(INDEX(Concat,MATCH(I3,Concat,1))=I3,INDEX(Concat,MATCH(I3,Concat,1)-1)<>I3),MATCH(I3,Concat,1),NA())
```