# VBA Solution To Long Time Calculation of Formulas When Running a Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file in the size of 13 MB. When I run my macro it calculates the first rows in 3 different worksheets and than I use `AutoFill` technique to next to 6000 rows and it takes to long time, something between 7-8 minutes. Most of the formulas are simple and should not take to long time, in my opinion. 
Someone has solution to my problem? Maybe a way that the calculation itself will happen in the module and in the workbook we will see just the result, the values?

My code starts with a `userform` and then calls to a module, that takes most of the time that the macro runs. as I said each of the 3 sheets includes next to 6000 rows. I want that in the end in the worksheet I I will see just the `values`.

```
Sub Formulas()

Call Columns

LR = VacationWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With VacationWS
    'Column D
        MyCol = .Range("D2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthCol - MyCol
        .Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-3],VacationWS!RC[-3],Visual!C[5],Lists!R3C3,Visual!C[4],Lists!R2C5)"
    'Column E
        MyCol = .Range("E2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthBefore - MyCol
        .Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-4],VacationWS!RC[-4],Visual!C[4],Lists!R4C3,Visual!C[3],Lists!R5C5)"
    'Column F
        MyCol = .Range("F2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthCol - MyCol
        .Range("F2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-5],VacationWS!RC[-5],Visual!C[3],Lists!R2C3,Visual!C[2],Lists!R2C5)"
    'Column G
        .Range("G2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]+RC[-2]-RC[-1]"
    'Column H
        MyCol = .Range("H2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthCol - MyCol
        .Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-7],VacationWS!RC[-7],Visual!C[1],Lists!R4C3,Visual!C,Lists!R5C5)"
    'Column I
        .Range("I2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"

    'Delete unnecessary rows
    .Range("D2:I2").AutoFill Destination:=VacationWS.Range("D2:I" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
    .Range("A1:I1").AutoFilter
    .Range("$A$1:$I$" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="0"
     On Error Resume Next
    .Range("A2:I" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .ShowAllData

End With


With IllnessWS
    'Column D
        MyCol = .Range("D2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthCol - MyCol
        .Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-3],IllnessWS!RC[-3],Visual!C[5],Lists!R3C3,Visual!C[4],Lists!R3C5)"
    'Column E
        MyCol = .Range("E2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthBefore - MyCol
        .Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-4],IllnessWS!RC[-4],Visual!C[4],Lists!R4C3,Visual!C[3],Lists!R6C5)"
    'Column F
        MyCol = .Range("F2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthCol - MyCol
        .Range("F2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-5],IllnessWS!RC[-5],Visual!C[3],Lists!R2C3,Visual!C[2],Lists!R3C5)"
    'Column G
        .Range("G2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]+RC[-2]-RC[-1]"
    'Column H
        MyCol = .Range("H2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthCol - MyCol
        .Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-7],IllnessWS!RC[-7],Visual!C[1],Lists!R4C3,Visual!C,Lists!R6C5)"
    'Column I
        .Range("I2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"

    'Delete unnecessary rows
    .Range("D2:I2").AutoFill Destination:=IllnessWS.Range("D2", "I" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
    .Range("A1:I1").AutoFilter
    .Range("$A$1:$I$" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="0"
     On Error Resume Next
    .Range("A2:I" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .ShowAllData

    'Delete what is equal to 90 or more in column H
    .Range("$A$1:$I$" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">=90", Operator:=xlAnd
    .Range("A2:I" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .ShowAllData

End With


With HealingWS
    'Column D
        MyCol = .Range("D2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthCol - MyCol
        .Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-3],HealingWS!RC[-3],Visual!C[5],Lists!R3C3,Visual!C[4],Lists!R4C5)"
    'Column E
        MyCol = .Range("E2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthBefore - MyCol
        .Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-4],HealingWS!RC[-4],Visual!C[4],Lists!R4C3,Visual!C[3],Lists!R7C5)"
    'Column F
        .Range("F2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]+RC[-2]"
    'Column G
        MyCol = .Range("G2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthCol - MyCol
        .Range("G2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-6],HealingWS!RC[-6],Visual!C[2],Lists!R4C3,Visual!C[1],Lists!R7C5)"
    'Column H
        .Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"

    'Delete unnecessary rows
    .Range("D2:H2").AutoFill Destination:=HealingWS.Range("D2:H" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
    .Range("A1:H1").AutoFilter
    .Range("$A$1:$H$" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="0"
     On Error Resume Next
    .Range("A2:H" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .ShowAllData

'Specific for June in HealingWS (Goes to Null)
    With Lists
        If MonthName = .Range("A7").Value Then
            HealingWS.Range("E2").Value = 0
            HealingWS.Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=HealingWS.Range("E2:E" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
        End If
    End With
End With

'January formulas change
If MonthName = Lists.Range("A2").Value Then
    With VacationWS
        .Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(December!C[7],December!C[-4],VacationWS!RC[-4],December!C[4],Lists!R4C3,December!C[3],Lists!R5C5)"
        .Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=VacationWS.Range("E2:E" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With

    With IllnessWS
        .Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(December!C[7],December!C[-4],îçìä!RC[-4],December!C[4],Lists!R4C3,December!C[3],Lists!R6C5)"
        .Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=IllnessWS.Range("E2:E" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With

    With HealingWS
        .Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(December!C[7],December!C[-4],HealingWS!RC[-4],December!C[4],Lists!R4C3,December!C[3],Lists!R7C5)"
        .Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=HealingWS.Range("E2:E" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With


End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to add `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the beginning and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end. Additionaly add: `Application.screenupdating  = false` at the beginning and `application.screenupdating = true` at the end. What are the results now?

Comment: @KazimierzJawor About Calculation Manual, it makes the macro slower, I already tried it. screenupdating  - I have it in my macro, as I said - the part here is in the middle of the code - the code starts in UserForm.

Comment: Just in case: Make sure your calculation have the correct direction (from top to bottom and from left to right). E.g If you calculate in A1 `=B1+C1` (which is from right to left) it is slower than calculating in C1 `=A1+B1` (which is from left to right). This already slow me off a lot in big and complicated worksheets.

Comment: try code like this `VacationWS.Range("G2:G5000").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]+RC[-2]-RC[-1]"`

Comment: Since your code seems to be working (albeit slowly), you might want to post your question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jsotola I tried it, takes the same time

Comment: @VincentG - I posted there too, no answers there too

Comment: i may be wrong on this ..... your formulas refer to whole columns in several places in each formula   
 ... using FormulaR1C1 hides it at first glance... this is your first formula 
 `=SUMIFS(Visual!C[10],Visual!C[-3],VacationWS!RC[-3],Visual!C[5],Lists!R3C3,Visual!C[4],Lists!R2C5)`  ............................................................................................................................................................................. this is the resulting formula in the cell
`=SUMIFS(Visual!N:N,Visual!A:A,VacationWS!A2,Visual!I:I,Lists!$C$3,Visual!H:H,Lists!$E$2)`

Comment: @jsotola, yes you are right. what can I do about it? is there a way I could make the calculation and get the answer as value in the worksheet?

Answer (score 2):

SUMIFS are computationally expensive, and should be used sparingly. You're putting them into 14 columns and then copying down. If they are all going down 6000 rows then that's a staggering 84,000 SUMIFS. Potentially pointed at pretty sizeable ranges. Train. Wreck.

Get rid of them. Use a PivotTable instead. And you'll see that things will takes mere seconds, not minutes.

I wrote an article on this sometime back at https://chandoo.org/wp/2014/01/17/big-trouble-in-little-spreadsheet/ that might be of interest.

And you might also be interested in an answer of mine here at SO some time back, where I compare a whole bunch of different approaches to summing on multiple conditions: [Optimizing Excel formulas - SUMPRODUCT vs SUMIFS/COUNTIFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745964/optimizing-excel-formulas-sumproduct-vs-sumifs-countifs/32488911#32488911)

One of those was something called Range Slicing, which will be about the fastest way of doing things if you're determined to use formulas. But while lightning fast, it's tricky to set up and hard for others to get their heads around. Which brings us back to the PivotTable again. PivotTables were designed for just the type of thing you're doing. They are by far a better solution here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will read now the links you gave me and who knows maybe you will be the one who opened my mind, it is a new model so I am open for changes

Comment: You should also read up on PowerPivot and PowerQuery. There's been a quiet revolution going on under Excel's hood recently. It is now an incredible database/transformation tool. Plenty of great videos on YouTube, and also great content on the web from the likes of Ken Puls, Rob Collie, Jon Acampora, Mike Girvin, and Chandoo. Google them, and prepare to be amazed.