# Why is this sumproduct function causing my excel to hang for 20-40 minutes?

Tags: excel

After several restarts, I learned that my Excel file hangs because of this. I turned off auto calculation because my excel keeps hanging every time I input a value in a cell. But when I press the save button, it will then compute and hang my excel again.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Payroll - Extra'!$C$2:$C$1048576)*('Payroll - Extra'!$C$1=A3)*('Payroll - Extra'!$A$2:$A$1048576='Payroll Tables and Settings'!$V$3)*('Payroll - Extra'!$B$2:$B$1048576='Payroll Tables and Settings'!$W$3))
```

The fields that I want summed up are the columns of each employee as shown in the image below:
[image: Columns to be summed]

The output will be used for the employee's payslip as shown below:
[image: Output]

Comment: Did it occur to you at all that including the column labels (e.g. A, B, O, etc) in the sample data images (that now have to be retyped by anyone proofing a response) might have been important?

Comment: Actually I was revising it just now. I initially didn't think of adding pictures sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

Change `Extra'!$O$2:$O$1048576` to,

```
'Payroll - Extra'!$O$2:INDEX('Payroll - Extra'!$O:$O, match(1e99, 'Payroll - Extra'!$O:$O))
```

... and `'Payroll - Extra'!$B$2:$B$1048576` to,

```
'Payroll - Extra'!$B$2:INDEX('Payroll - Extra'!$B:$B, match(1e99, 'Payroll - Extra'!$O:$O))
```

... and all similar likewise. Those assume 'Payroll - Extra'!$O:$O is numeric.

Avoid full column references when using SUMPRODUCT or similar cyclic calculation functions.

Comment: Thanks i'll try this out

Comment: Acording to your revised images, the `'Payroll - Extra'!$O:$O` in `match(1e99, 'Payroll - Extra'!$O:$O)` could be changed to column A, B or C.

Comment: Yes noted. Sorry again for that

Answer (score 2):

Your workbook is slow to calculate because you are asking it to do over 3 million multiplications and comparisons for each SUMPRODUCT formula the workbook contains (don't know how many SUMPRODUCT formulas you have).

Assuming that you don't really have 1048576 rows of data and that when you press Ctrl-End on the worksheet it only goes to the end of the real data then you should use SUMIFS with full column references ($A:$A) rather than SUMPRODUCT because SUMIFS only calculates on the used range rather than all the rows.

It would also be better to convert your data to an Excel Table and use structured references.

Comment: would that be 3M calculations or 3M³ calculations?

Comment: AFAIK its 3M ... I suppose we could design an experiment to find out!

Comment: In addition to what Charles says above, SUMIFS is also quicker than SUMPRODUCT...up to 15 times faster in the mammoth data set I talk about at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745964/optimizing-excel-formulas-sumproduct-vs-sumifs-countifs/32488911#32488911. But that's in an extreme case where there are in fact over 1 million rows being crunched. You probably won't notice any difference with most data sets.