# Filtering: AODB vs Autofilter vs SQLite

Tags: sql, excel, vba, sqlite, autofilter

I have an Excel sheet with data in about 100,000 rows, 16 columns. I have to extract data (one value from the 1 row I find) from this table a few thousand times. I have been using Autofilter to extract this value, but have also tried AODB/SQL statements to see if I can improve the speed of the queries.

The data is sorted by column 1. When I use Autofilter, it takes on average 0.3 seconds to get my value, no matter the location of the value. AODB takes between 0.1 to 0.6 seconds to find the value, depending on where the value is in the table (if the value is near the top of the table, it takes 0.1 seconds, while if the data is near the end of the table it can take up to 0.6 seconds). I had expected the AODB to be much faster than Autofilter, but it seems that on average they are about the same.

When I import this data into SQLite and use a tool such as SQLiteStudio, the query returns the value in less than 0.01s!

Can I change anything in my code to to speed up the Queries in VBA?

Codes are below. AODB method:

```
Sub AODB_method()
'Freeze Screen and other options to run code faster
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

 Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
 Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
 Dim vv As Double
 Dim Time2 As Double

Time2 = Timer

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

With ThisWorkbook
    If Application.Version < 12 Then
        cn.ConnectionString = _
          "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & .FullName & ";" & _
          "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
    Else
        cn.ConnectionString = _
          "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & .FullName & ";" & _
          "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"



     End If

     cn.Open

    Set rs = cn.Execute("SELECT [Cl] FROM [Table1$] WHERE [Wind]=150 AND [Weight]=200000 AND [Altitude] = 20000 AND [ISA] = 0")

    vv = rs.Fields(0).Value

    rs.Close
    cn.Close
End With

'Turn Options on again
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True


Debug.Print "Connection Time: " & Timer - Time2
End Sub
```

Autofilter method:

```
Sub Autofilter_method()

'Freeze Screen and other options to run code faster
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim vv As Double
Dim Time2 As Double

Time2 = Timer

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A1:H1") 
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=0
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=200000 
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=20000 
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=-150 


        End With


    End With


vv = Range("H" & finallastrow("Table1", "H")).Value

'Turn Options on again
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

Debug.Print "Connection Time: "; Timer - Time2
End Sub
```

Some Notes:

- I am using Excel 2013. The Jet OLEDB provider seemed faster but I can't get the value to be saved in variable vv (I get an error).
- When Wind is -150 (Column1, -150 is near the top of the table), the AODB query runs in 0.1s, while a wind value of +150 takes 0.6 seconds.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If your code is working but needs optimizing it may be a candidate for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than SO.

Comment: Thanks QHarr, I'll post in code review.

Comment: Good luck. Also, delete question from here.

Comment: Note: It's ADODB, not AODB.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Code Review is the better place to ask, as agreed by the OP

Comment: Research on PowerPivot for large amounts of data (row/column count more than Excel can handle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving my spreadsheets to Microsoft Access, and used ADODB/SQL Queries from Excel to retrieve values from the Access database. This helped speed up my code by approx 10x, so definitely worth the move.

Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Those methods are probably going to be slow compared to using one of the following:

- A PivotTable, combined with the GETPIVOTDATA function
- The Advanced Filter (not to be confused with the AutoFilter)
- Range Slicing on sorted data, which will trump everything else in terms of speed.

...either of which can be called from VBA.
For further elaboration of these, see my answer at [Optimizing Excel formulas - SUMPRODUCT vs SUMIFS/COUNTIFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745964/optimizing-excel-formulas-sumproduct-vs-sumifs-countifs/32488911#32488911)