# Sheet EnableCalculation Working Intermitently

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a spreadsheet for my company and I am having trouble with the EnableCalculation function. We copy large chunks of data and paste them into a workbook. To expedite this process, I 'freeze' sheets by turning the EnableCalculation to False as shown in the example.

*Disabled*

[image: image description]

Without  this, Excel slows to a crawl while background calculations are done as the data is being pasted.

In the macro that does the calculation for this workbook once all the data has been pasted, I re-enable the calculation by setting EnableCalculation to True.

*Re-Enabled*

[image: image description]

The issue that I have found, however, is that sometimes the sheets calculate properly but other times they do not with seemingly no rhyme or reason. It is extremely frustrating for it to be so unpredictable. Is there a way to ensure that the sheets calculate when they are supposed to? Thanks,

Comment: Try `Application.CalculateFullRebuild` if you want to be sure everything is fully calculated.  Are you using any custom UDF's in your workbook?  If Yes do they all have the required parameters to capture all dependencies?

Comment: Thanks Tim, I will try that and, no, this workbook does not have any UDFs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to ensure sheets calculate when they should do: Refactor the workbook so that you avoid the bottlenecks that forced you to put it into manual calc mode in the first place. Then switch calc mode back to Automatic and leave it there! Manual calc mode is just too dangerous, and almost always completely avoidable.

Common reasons why spreadsheets get so slow that users have to switch to manual calc mode include:

- Volatile formulas (OFFSET, INDIRECT, TODAY etc) with large
  calculation chains hanging off them. See [my blog post here](https://chandoo.org/wp/2014/03/03/handle-volatile-functions-like-they-are-dynamite/). I've slashed recalc time from minutes to seconds just by addressing this in isolation.
- Overuse of SUMPRODUCT for cases that can be handled by SUMIFS
  or PivotTables. [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745964/optimizing-excel-formulas-sumproduct-vs-sumifs-countifs/32488911#32488911).
- Resource-intensive lookups done on unsorted data. [See my post
  here.](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2015/04/23/how-much-faster-is-the-double-vlookup-trick) Using a binary match on sorted data can reduce recalc time
  by minutes.

Charles Williams has a great article on [finding and optimizing bottle necks here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/excel-tips-for-optimizing-performance-obstructions).

Comment: Jeffrey, thanks. I agree with you that it is better to remove the need for manual calculation. I already tried to optimize the sheet. I have removed all the volatile formulas and do not have any SUMPRODUCTs. I will have to investigate the double-VLOOKUP trick.