# calculations are not disabled on the opening of the workbook, although calculations are set to manual

Tags: vba, excel

Dear community members,

We have disable the calculations in the workbook through below macro:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False

If Application.Calculation <> xlCalculationManual Then
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Else
End If
End Sub
```

---

But still when the workbook opens ,it calculates the formulas and takes some time to open. I ideally want to open the workbook without any initial calculations.
I tried the below code but it is not giving satisfactory results.

### is there a ideal way to disable all the calculations??

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()


ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.EnableEvents = True

If Application.Calculation <> xlCalculationManual Then
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Else
End If
End Sub
```

---

Would really appreciate you help on this.

Comment: Question: Why does the workbook take so long to calculate anyway? Instead of attempting to disable calculations, you will probably find that if you refactor the workbook, calculation will be fast enough that you can simply leave the workbook in automatic mode. Check out my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674649/sheet-enablecalculation-working-intermitently/48676251#48676251 for more.

Comment: Can you confirm, is the above code saved in 'ThisWorkbook' or in a Module?