# Sumproduct with 5 criterias from another workbook takes too long to run

Tags: excel, optimization, excel-formula

I'm trying to lookup 5 different criteria from another file. The formula I'm using is below:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(('[WorkBook]Sheet'!$A:$A=$A9), 
('[WorkBook]Sheet'!$H:$H=$P9), 
('[WorkBook]Sheet'!$D:$D=S$5), 
(('[WorkBook]Sheet'!$E:$E="String1")+('[WorkBook]Sheet'!$E:$E="String2")) )>=1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

I could get the result in the first few cells. However, when I copy paste (or drag) the formula to the table bottom, it takes forever to calculate using 4 processors. Eventually, excel crashed.

Is it possible there's too many criteria used, and they are cross-referencing between 2 files, and on top of that, I nested it with IF function, and therefore the formula is too heavy to run on multiple cells (about 150k cells)? If so, can anyone suggest a better formula?

Comment: You need to chop down your full column references but that cannot be done without knowing whether there are text or numbers in each.

Comment: Hi, column A,D,and E contain text, while column H contains dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That SUMPRODUCT has nothing but booleans making it a COUNTIFS. The OR condition is handled with SUM(COUNTIFS(...)) and a hard-coded string array.

```
=AND(SUM(COUNTIFS('[WorkBook]Sheet'!$A:$A, $A9, 
                  '[WorkBook]Sheet'!$H:$H, $P9,
                  '[WorkBook]Sheet'!$D:$D, S$5, 
                  '[WorkBook]Sheet'!$E:$E, {"String1", "String2"})))
```

COUNTIFS can use full column references without calculation lag penalty while SUMPRODUCT is penalized greatly.

The wrapping AND does nothing more than convert a number to TRUE/FALSE.

Here is your original SUMPRODUCT with all ranges cut down to the row containing the last date in column H.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(('[WorkBook]Sheet'!$a$2:index('[WorkBook]Sheet'!$a:$a, match(1e99, '[WorkBook]Sheet'!$h:$h))=$A9),
               ('[WorkBook]Sheet'!$h$2:index('[WorkBook]Sheet'!$h:$h, match(1e99, '[WorkBook]Sheet'!$h:$h))=$P9), 
               ('[WorkBook]Sheet'!$d$2:index('[WorkBook]Sheet'!$d:$d, match(1e99, '[WorkBook]Sheet'!$h:$h))=S$5), 
              (('[WorkBook]Sheet'!$e$2:index('[WorkBook]Sheet'!$e:$e, match(1e99, '[WorkBook]Sheet'!$h:$h))="String1")+ 
               ('[WorkBook]Sheet'!$e$2:index('[WorkBook]Sheet'!$e:$e, match(1e99, '[WorkBook]Sheet'!$h:$h))="String2")))>=1, true, false)
```

Yes, that may look complicated but in fact it does much less work than the full column reference model.

Comment: The reason I used SUMPRODUCT is because when I close the source file, the formula result in #VALUE error. Is there another way of doing this and avoiding that error?

Comment: @AlfredMaz - I've added the SUMPRODUCT version with column references cut down to what is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing across files is something I avoid like the plague. Is there a concrete reason why you can't simply use say a PivotTable in the same workbook as the data exists, and just filter the PivotTable to show what you need to show?

Much much simpler. Much much safer. Much much faster. To see this and other alternatives explained in detail, check out my answer at [Optimizing Excel formulas - SUMPRODUCT vs SUMIFS/COUNTIFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745964/optimizing-excel-formulas-sumproduct-vs-sumifs-countifs/32488911#32488911)