# Criteria input for Database Function in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, database

The general inputs to database functions in excel (DSUM, DCOUNT, DMAX, etc.) are 
database, field, and criteria. Normally, the criteria is another range created outside of the database. What I'm thinking is: Is there a way to input the criteria range without the need to create new cells?

Suppose I have a table "Survey" with headers "Name","Address","Age", and "Gender". I wish to get the average of age of entries who lives in "Quezon" and who are older than 25 years. This formula works: `=DAVERAGE(Survey[#All],"Age",B1:C2)`. Why doesn't this formula work: `{=DAVERAGE(Survey[#All],"Age",{"Address","Age";"Quezon",">25"})}`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some functions accept ranges, some don't. This is one that don't. Nor does the Advanced Filter, which is pretty similar. You'd have to use SUMIFS or similar if you don't want to set up criteria ranges. Me, I'd just use a PivotTable and slicers to filter and return the records I'm interested in. You might be interested in my answer at [Optimizing Excel formulas - SUMPRODUCT vs SUMIFS/COUNTIFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745964/optimizing-excel-formulas-sumproduct-vs-sumifs-countifs/32488911#32488911) that discusses the relative efficiencies of these things.

Comment: I see. I'm already using PivotTables and a lot of IF operations, but I thought these database functions have a potential to be more convenient in some of my files so I gave it a try (though it doesn't seem to be the case)Thank you for your response! :)